# What is the best way to group and aggregate and sum tree data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, hierarchical

Given a self referencing table

```
Item 
-------------
Id (pk)
ParentId (fk)
```

With a related table of associated values

```
ItemValue
-------------
ItemId (fk)
Amount
```

And some sample data

```
Item                       ItemValues 
Id      ParentId           ItemId      Amount
--------------------       ----------------------
1       null               1           10
2       1                  3           40
3       1                  3           20
4       2                  4           10
5       2                  5           30
6       null
7       6
8       7
```

I need a sproc to take `Item.Id` and return the direct children with sums of all `ItemValue.Amounts` for the them, their children and their children all the way down the tree.

For example, if `1` is passed in, the tree would be `2, 3, 4, 5` the direct children are `2, 3` the output would be

```
 ItemId    Amount
 ------------------
 2         40     (values from ItemIds 4 & 5)
 3         60     (values from ItemId 3)
```

What sort of approaches should be applied to make achieve this behavior?

I am considering using a CTE, but am wondering if there is a better/faster approach.

Comment: SQL Server 2005, I'll retag too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A recursive CTE like this would work, assuming your hierarchy doesn't go too deep:

```
declare @ParentId int;
set @ParentId = 1;

;with 
  Recurse as (
    select 
      a.Id as DirectChildId
    , a.Id
    from Item a 
    where ParentId = @ParentId
    union all
    select
      b.DirectChildId
    , a.Id
    from Item a 
    join Recurse b on b.Id = a.ParentId
    )
select
  a.DirectChildId, sum(b.Amount) as Amount
from Recurse a
left join ItemValues b on a.Id = b.ItemId
group by
  DirectChildId;
```

A non-CTE method would require some form of iteration, cursor-based or otherwise.  Since it's a stored proc, its a possibility, and if there's a lot data to recurse through, it would probably scale better, so long as you slice the data appropriately.

If the clustered index is on Id, add a non-clustered index on ParentId. As a covering index, it will satisfy the initial seek w/out a bookmark lookup. The clustered index will then help with the recursive join.

If the clustered index is already on ParentId instead, add a non-clustered index on Id. Together, they will be virtually equivalent to the above. For ItemValues, you may want a index on (ItemId) INCLUDE (Amount), if the actual table is wider than this.

Comment: "assuming your hierarchy doesn't go too deep" it doesn't, but what would be the problem if it did?

Comment: Recursion depth is limited to 100 by default on SQL Server. You can specify as high as 32767 with the MAXRECURSION query hint, but I assume it does not scale linearly with volume above a certain threshold. It doesn't seem an issue for your situation, though, since you will be specifying one parent at a time. So long as you have it indexed properly and recursion depth is reasonable (under 100?), performance shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: You can go to infinite recursion with a CTE. Set MAXRECURSION = 0. It says this in BOL.

Answer (score 0):

Could you store your data as in the nested set model (here is a MySQL [reference](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) but the ideas are generic across databases)?  If so then the operations to find the value you are looking for would be fairly simple.

Answer (score 0):

Does this have to be handled in the database?  I would suggest bringing the necessary data into your BLL and performing the recursion there.