# Sum totals of parent-child relationship in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

There is the following table called DimAufbau

[image]

As you can see, this table holds a parent-child relation using "Relation" field to hold the id of the parent.

Each node in this table can hold more nodes OR hold accounts.

[image]

As you can see, Betriebliche have some accounts associated but Erlöse and GuV can not have accounts (actually this is a restriction I found using SSAS but by now it is not a problem)

The association between DimAufabu and Accounts is the following:

[image]

**Now, the problem:** We have a SSRS report called ReportKore that must show the tree structure of Aufbau table showing the sums of some fields.

[image]

The dataset to fill that report uses the following query but it not show the sums for the parents nods as they dont't have accounts associated:

```
;WITH aufbautree(id, relation, Bezeichnung, AufbauLevel) AS (

  SELECT
    id, 
    relation, 
    Bezeichnung, 
    1 AufbauLevel
  FROM [dbo].[DimAufbau]
  WHERE
    relation IS NULL 
    and ([DimAufbau].id in (@aufbau))

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
    da.id, 
    da.relation, 
    da.Bezeichnung, 
    tr.AufbauLevel + 1
  FROM
    [dbo].[DimAufbau] da 
    INNER JOIN aufbautree tr 
        ON da.relation = tr.id)

SELECT
  at.*, 
  fk.BetragIst, 
  fk.BetragPlan, 
  dkbez.Bezeichnung AS KontoBezeichnung
FROM
  aufbautree at 
  LEFT JOIN DimAufbauKonto auk 
    ON auk.AufbauId = at.id 
  LEFT JOIN DimKonto dk 
    ON auk.KontoID = dk.id 
  LEFT JOIN DimKontoBezeichnung AS dkbez 
    ON dkbez.Id = dk.BezeichnungId 
  LEFT JOIN FaktKore fk 
    ON fk.DimKontoId = dk.id 
  LEFT JOIN DimKostenstelle AS dko 
    ON fk.DimKostenstelleId = dko.Id 
  LEFT JOIN DimMandant AS dm 
    ON fk.DimMandantId = dm.Id 
  LEFT JOIN DimZeit AS dz 
    ON fk.DimZeitId = dz.Id
```

I really tried a lot to see the way how to also show the sum of the parent nodes but my CTE knowledge is limited. Hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Aren't you able to configure this in SSRS? That's my first thought at least. Maybe this is helpful? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220511.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your query utilizes CTE only to construct logical tree based on the self-referencing structure in the DimAufbau table.

There is no optimal way to get your leaf value aggregation (from Accounts) without adding that data to the query.

However, you mention that there is no Account table relation in your final output.
So what you have in output is the following:

1. **id** - tree node id
2. **da.relation** - tree self-reference (reference to parent)
3. **da.Bezeichnung** - tree node name
4. **tr.AufbauLevel** - tree node level
5. **fk.BetragIst** - unknown?
6. **fk.BetragPlan** - unknown?
7. **dkbez.Bezeichnung** - tree node konto description (leaf description?)

I don't see anything related to "Total" in your report, so there must be another data source or something else that aggregates/outputs the data in that column.

At the end, if you want to get data from Accounts table in your SQL query, you have to join that table in your query. It doesn't have to be in the CTE body, but I'm not sure it will be optimal.

Here's the scheme you could use if appropriate:

```
;WITH aufbautree(id, relation, Bezeichnung, AufbauLevel) AS (
  ...
)
SELECT
  at.*, 
  ...,
  sum(a.YourValueField) as ValueSum
FROM
  aufbautree at 
  JOIN ...
  LEFT JOIN Accounts a
    ON {your condition}
GROUP BY at.Id
```

If you need an example, [this link may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610893/what-is-the-best-way-to-group-and-aggregate-and-sum-tree-data).